# How can I deploy a set of SSIS Packages from an MSI on a different server

Tags: deployment, installation, windows-installer, ssis

We already have an existing MSI Installer (web deployment project - .vdproj) that we use to deploy our web application. This MSI only ever gets run on the **WEBSERVER**. It does the following

1. Configures up IIS
2. Installs the Web Application
3. GAC's any required assemblies
4. Unpacks & Runs SQL scripts against the DB via SqlCmd

Seperately we have about 7 or 8 DTSX Packages which we need to install on the **DBSERVER**. This is currently done manually. Someone XCopys the SSIS Deployment folder to DBSERVER. Runs the SSIS Deployment Manifest & chooses a file system deploy.

I don't have an awful lot of experience with MSI Installers (having inherited this one)
Is it possible to include all the DTSX Packages in the *Existing Installer* and install into the SQL Server instance on the **DBSERVER**, directly from the MSI being run on the **WEBSERVER**

Comment: How are you currently building the MSI? Is it a websetup project, WiX, something-else?

Comment: It's a Visual Studio Setup Project (.vdproj)

Comment: an y sample with full source code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this can be done with an MSI-based installer.

First, you need to decide on a setup authoring tool which supports IIS and SQL scripts. Each tool has its advantages and disadvantages, but many of them have dedicated support for what you need to do. This list may help: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_installation_software

After getting a tool, you can try configuring your installer and ask additional questions when you encounter a specific problem.

Edit:

There is no built-in support for handling DTSX packages in an MSI. However, you can install them using [custom actions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368066%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Perhaps this will help:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqlintegrationservices/thread/4a8ffc3a-ef79-4402-bf2e-d4a386b20fed

Comment: We already have a process / installer. a VDProj Web Deployment Project in our Solution. You build the installer project, and it spits out the MSI. We already have the IIS bit complete. We already have the SQL Scripts bit complete. My question related to adding the DTSX/SSIS Deployment to that already existing installer. I've updated the question to be more clear.

Comment: Thanks for the followup Cosmin.